# How to execute tasks in different server using Python Celery?

Tags: python, celery

Let's say I have three servers A, B & C. Server C will have the celery task code, and I need to execute them from servers A & B.

From the celery [documentation](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html#application), I see that there's a `task.py` file which is run as a celery worker

```
from celery import Celery

app = Celery('tasks', broker='pyamqp://guest@localhost//')

@app.task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

And then we have another python file (let's say `client.py`) which calls these tasks.

```
from tasks import add

add.delay(4, 4)
```

Here I can see that the `client.py` file is dependent on the `tasks.py` file as it's importing the `task` from the `tasks.py` file. If we are to run these two files in separate servers, we need to decouple them and somehow call the tasks without having to import the code. I am not able to figure out how to achieve that. So, how can it be done?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In general you do not do that. You deploy the same code (containing tasks) to both producers (clients) and consumers (workers). However, Celery is a cool piece of software and it allows you to actually schedule task without the need to distribute the code on the producer side. For that you *have to use* the [send_task()](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/reference/celery.html#celery.Celery.send_task) method. You have to configure producer with same parameters as your workers (same broker naturally, same serialization) and you must know the calling task name and its parameters in order to schedule its execution correctly.

Comment: I was able to call the task using the following format `celery.send_task('tasks.add', (2, 2))` without importing the task module into the client code. Thank you.